# Run-Time EGL Error: "Failed to Open Swrast" (Nix)

Tags: egl, nix

#### 1 Context

I have a private repo that builds via `nix` (in case it matters, the repo is a Haskell + Stack project). In particular, this repo has some low-level graphics dependencies, including (at the top level):

```
buildInputs = with pkgs; [ mesa
                           xorg.pixman
                           wayland-protocols
                           wayland
                           xorg.libX11
                           dbus
                           weston
                          ];
```

And the system which I'm building this repo on is an Arch Linux machine (with `nix` installed outside the package manager).

#### 2 Problem

The program compiles fine, however when I launch it I get the soul-crushing run-time error:

```
Loading module '/nix/store/98ipsxd20n5nw71q1kjpb5kyr55ysx7y-weston-2.0.0/lib/libweston-2/x11-backend.so'
Loading module '/nix/store/98ipsxd20n5nw71q1kjpb5kyr55ysx7y-weston-2.0.0/lib/libweston-2/gl-renderer.so'
EGL client extensions: EGL_EXT_client_extensions EGL_EXT_platform_base
               EGL_KHR_client_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_KHR_debug
               EGL_EXT_platform_wayland EGL_EXT_platform_x11
               EGL_MESA_platform_gbm
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to open swrast (search paths /run/opengl-driver/lib/dri)
failed to initialize display
EGL error state: EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED (0x3001)
Socket: wayland-0

program-name: user error (Failed compiling shader Shader {shaderID = 0})
```

#### 3 Inelegant Solution

The issue is that it's searching in `/run/opengl-driver/lib/dri`, which is a NixOS specific path. In fact -- when I build and launch this program on my secondary NixOS system, it compiles and runs just fine.

A horrendous hack to fix this issue on non-NixOS systems is to run:

```
sudo ln -s /nix/store/*-mesa-noglu-*-drivers /run/opengl-driver
```

**Question:** Is there a more elegant, Nixish solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but that is an open problem at the time of writing.

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/9415